# Java Refactor led to a Circular reference

Tags: java, refactoring, dependency-injection

I have this sort of code in a desktop app

This is just a JPanel that contains buttons and that sort of thing.

```
class ApplicationPanel {

   private Listener listener;

   public ApplicationPanel(){
      this.listener = new Listener(this);
   }
}
```

This adds the events to the controls in the JPanel above.

```
class Listener {

   private ApplicationPanel panel;

   public Listener(ApplicationPanel panel){
      this.panel = panel;
   }
}
```

Caller code would be like this

```
public void main(String[] args){
   ApplicationPanel panel = new ApplicationPanel();
}
```

If I try to apply dependency injection
And factories(later to be changed for Guice)

```
class ApplicationPanel {

   private Listener listener;

   public ApplicationPanel(){
      this(new Listener());
   }

   public ApplicationPanel(Listener listener){
      this.listener = listener;
   }
}

class Listener {

   private ApplicationPanel panel;

   public Listener(){
      this(new ApplicationPanel());
   }

   public Listener(ApplicationPanel panel){
      this.panel = panel;
   }
}
```

Caller code would be like this
As you can see, there's a circular dependency in this code
Whats the best way to solve this?

```
public void main(String[] args){
   Listener listener = new Listener(panel);
   ApplicationPanel panel = new ApplicationPanel(listener);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/2009/10/15/solve-the-circular-reference-problem-with-guice-and-spring/) on the topic; guice is smart enough, given the bindings you provide in your guice Module, to detect the circular reference and then use a temporary proxy so that the injection can be resolved.

Comment: Interesting approach, great to know (+1)

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is: When using dependency injection, always use default constructors and setters.

This way, you can create all your objects (no dependencies at this stage), call all the setters at once and then start using your objects.

Comment: One problem with always using default constructors with dependency injection is the fields cannot be "final", which means your classes cannot be immutable. Final fields and classes immutable makes it easier to make code thread-safe (it's not sufficient, but it helps)

Comment: @NamshubWriter I know. If you are using a container-managed solution, you have to let go of some things you would usually manage yourself. Immutability is one of them. Basically: the container is not going to change the values if you don't tell it to, so unless you do something stupid yourself, nobody is going to change the properties. I know, final is better, but that's the drawback for all the features you get through dependency injection.

Comment: Completely disagree. I use Guice extensively in my projects; I do not have to let go of final fields, and I can make objects immutable when they should be. While in some cases in might make sense to use setter injection, I disagree the statement that "when using dependency injection, always use default constructors". Final fields are not just syntactic sugar; they provide guarantees on when a change can be said to have been published to other objects. Final fields are also a form of executable documentation (when trying to reason about the code, you know the field cannot change).

Comment: @NamshubWriter: You're just hiding the dependency cycle better (and make it harder to debug if it breaks). If something can't be final because of a cyclic dependency, then insisting that it has to be final is like trying hard to introduce another bug.

Comment: @NamshubWriter: Good luck to the guy who has to fix bugs in that part of the code.

Comment: Here I was specifically commenting on "When using dependency injection, ALWAYS use default constructors" (emphasis added). I think that's bad advice, and three people apparently agree. You didn't say "When using dependency injection for classes with circular dependencies" (though since you can do that without using default constructors, "always" would be questionable there, too). As for the second comment, if you think my solution would be hard to maintain, please add a comment to my solution explaining why.

Comment: @NamshubWriter: Just like you, I want a uniform solution. So you make everything final and I always use constructors without arguments. As for your solution, I like it. +1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you cannot unittest `ApplicationPanel` with a fake `Listener` because `Listener` takes in an `ApplicationPanel` (if you use the default constructor for `Listener` then the listener would have a field referencing a real `ApplicationPanel`). You could use a mock `Listener` with a mocking framework, but in this case I think the circular dependencies could indicate a code smell.

The real problem with this circular dependency is that the `Listener` receives a reference to the `ApplicationPanel` before the `ApplicationPanel` has completed construction. This can cause thread safety issues. Even if the code path isn't multi-threaded, the `Listener` might make a call to the `ApplicationPanel` that causes an event to be sent, before the `ApplicationPanel` has initialized the listener list!

Instead, pass the data to the listener when it receives events:

```
public interface Listener {

  void onApplicationChanged(ApplicationPanel panel){
  }
}
```

The more traditional way to add the listener to the object that is sending the events is to make a method call:

```
public class ApplicationPanel {
  private List<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Listener>();

  public void addListener(Listener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }
}
```

If you want the class that sends the events to use the constructor to specify the listeners, and you want to use Guice, look at [Multibinder](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html). The `ApplicationPanel` would look like this:

```
public class ApplicationPanel {
  private Set<Listener> listeners;

  @Inject
  public ApplicationPanel(Set<Listener> listeners) {
    listeners = new HashSet<Listener>(listeners);
  }
}
```